# Related category on a single page

Tags: categories

Been trying for days to figure this one out. How do I extract entries from a channel and display only entries related to a category? How do I pull in the related photo? I have this code below but it pulls in all the photos. I don't think I'm doing doing this right.

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug('spring-summer').first() %}

{% for post in craft.entries.section('product').relatedTo({targetElement: category}) %}

    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ post.price }}</p>

    {% for product in craft.entries.find() %}
        {% for image in product.photo %}
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl('bottom') }}" />
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set up your category, you check the **Categories in this group have their own URLs** box, and you give the category a URL (suppose it is `category/{slug}`), and a template (suppose it is `category/_entry`). Now in the `category/_entry.html` template, `category` will be defined (the way `entry` is defined on the template for a section entry).

[How do I list the entries related to a category?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entries-related-to-category) (tucked away in the Get Help section of the Craft website) describes how to fetch and list the entries related to a category:

```
{# Fetch all of the entries related to this category #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}

{# Output them #}
{% for entry in entries %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to narrow the entries down to a single section, then fetch them like this:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySectionHandle').relatedTo(category) %}
```